# Multithreading implementation pattern

Tags: php, sockets, redis, pthreads

First of all, i'm using pthreads. So the scenario is this: There are servers of a game that send logs over UDP to an ip and port you give them. I'm building an application that will receive those logs, process them and insert them in a mysql database. Since i'm using blocking sockets because the number of servers will never go over 20-30, I'm thinking that i will create a thread for each socket that will receive and process logs for that socket. All the mysql infromation that needs to be inserted in the database will be send to a redis queue where it will get processed by another php running. Is this ok, or better, is it reliable ?

[image: Design info]

Answer (score -2):

Don't use php for long running processes (php script used for inserting in your graph). The language is designed for web requests (which die after a couple of ms or max seconds). You will run into memory problems all the time.